# session {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, visual-studio-2012

I am new to ASP.NET and I am stuck in a problem. I am trying to manage already written website. I have this error when I reach following line:

```
if (Session["usertype"].Equals("2"))
{

}
```

`Session["usertype"]` is already assigned on previous page. On this current page, I loose all of the session variables(I checked it in debug).

Session is assigned following way after login

```
Session["usertype"] = "2"
```

Page after login, refreshes after 10 seconds. And that is the place where I loose sessions.
Please let me know, what can be wrong here.

Comment: which code you store value into Session?

Comment: Paste your full `Session` code here..

Comment: why are you checking with `.Equals` you should be checking that by using `==` instead also try this instead 
`if ( (string)Session["usertype"] == 2.ToString()) {}` try to assign values to variables instead when ever necessary .. even more important show how and where you are assigning `Session["usertype"]`

Comment: Try this:String s = Request.QueryString["usertype"];

Comment: @coder why would you check the query string if you expect the value to be in session?

Comment: @Marc-As the OP said that this is already assigned in previous page and not getting that session variable in the current page.

Comment: Are you calling `Session.RemoveAll()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: @IvanG, Nop, I am not.

Comment: @SonerGönül, Session["usertype"] = "2", just after login. But when that page refreshes after 10 sec. I dont find any session variables.

Comment: @coder, Request.QueryString is for http post right? Not for sessions.

Answer (score 2):

Just check that if Session variable is Null-

```
     if( Session["usertype"] != null )
    {
         //Now check your condition here
    }
   else {
           //Perform any operation
        }
```

Comment: It is NULL, thats what the error says. My question is, How it got lost?

Comment: try to declare your session variable in Global.asax in the Session_Start block or this problem might be caused by using In-proc session state.

Comment: I am using "In Process" in session state. What else should I do?

Comment: you should use Out proc (State Server) for maintaining session.

Comment: How? and what is the benefit?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/157996/how-can-we-do-inproc-and-outproc-session.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a `NullReferenceException`, then the session value is coming back as `null`. You should probably check that:

```
var userType = (string)Session["usertype"];
if(userType == null) {
    // .. things to do if no session value
} else {
    // test "2" etc
}
```

It could be that session-state is disabled, or simply didn't actually get set a value.

Comment: How can I check it in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WebForms or MVC? In WebForms, session state is not availabloe until after the page Init.

Answer (score 0):

is your process more than 10 seconds?
you can **change** the length of the session **in IIS**. Open IIS, click your website, select the Session State (ASP.NET tab), see the State-Server, change the Time-out (default: 10 second)

Comment: In my IIS, I am using "In Process" as Session State. Is it not correct? And does VS 2012 Debug uses settings of IIS?

Comment: "In Process" Session State has a default timeout of 20 minutes. I think that's enough. but if the session reset every 10 seconds may be the default value changed. Open IIS Manager, In Features View, double-click ASP, On the ASP page, under Services, expand Session Properties, In the Time-out field, enter a time-out value. (IIS Server 7 not IIS Express)

Comment: it is 20 min. It hasn't changed.

Comment: please check In webconfig file...<system.web>...<sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>...</system.web> or your session reset by another modul running in your web farm or you not define your session variables in global.asax. this video may be help http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-35-applications/session-level-objects